# TypeScript union types becoming intersection types confusion

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics, union-types

A code block paints 1000 words:

Example of something that I can't get my head round.

Why is `mySomething` an invalid type for the expected argument of `mySet()`?

It looks like `mySomething` should be an 'intersection type' of the 'parts of the union type on `my` and `mySet`'.

I've also tried creating a type for `info` and instead of `T extends 'a'|'b'|'c'|'d'`, used `T extends keyof InfoType` but with the same results.

I'm sure I'll get this one day, help much appreciated.

```
    type Something = Map<string,boolean> | Map<string,number>

    const [a, setA] = useState(new Map<string,boolean>());
    const [b, setB] = useState(new Map<string,boolean>());
    const [c, setC] = useState(new Map<string,number>());
    const [d, setD] = useState(new Map<string,number>());

    const info = {
      a: [a, setA] as [Map<string,boolean>,React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<Map<string, boolean>>>],
      b: [b, setB] as [Map<string,boolean>,React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<Map<string, boolean>>>],
      c: [c, setC] as [Map<string,number>,React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<Map<string, number>>>],
      d: [d, setD] as [Map<string,number>,React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<Map<string, number>>>],
    }

    const f = <T extends 'a'|'b'|'c'|'d'>(t: T) => {
      const [my, mySet] = info[t];
      const mySomething = (t === 'a'||t==='b'? new Map<string,boolean>():new Map<string,number>()) // tried also with: as Something;
      mySet(mySomething);
      mySet(my); // <- this also has the same error
    };
```

Error:

```
const mySomething: Something
Argument of type 'Something' is not assignable to parameter of type '(Map<string, boolean> & Map<string, number>) | (Map<string, boolean> & ((prevState: Map<string, number>) => Map<string, number>)) | (((prevState: Map<string, boolean>) => Map<...>) & Map<...>) | (((prevState: Map<...>) => Map<...>) & ((prevState: Map<...>) => Map<...>))'.
  Type 'Map<string, boolean>' is not assignable to type '(Map<string, boolean> & Map<string, number>) | (Map<string, boolean> & ((prevState: Map<string, number>) => Map<string, number>)) | (((prevState: Map<string, boolean>) => Map<...>) & Map<...>) | (((prevState: Map<...>) => Map<...>) & ((prevState: Map<...>) => Map<...>))'.
    Type 'Map<string, boolean>' is not assignable to type '((prevState: Map<string, boolean>) => Map<string, boolean>) & Map<string, number>'.
      Type 'Map<string, boolean>' is not assignable to type '(prevState: Map<string, boolean>) => Map<string, boolean>'.
        Type 'Map<string, boolean>' provides no match for the signature '(prevState: Map<string, boolean>): Map<string, boolean>'.ts(2345)
```

Comment: what about passing the `Something` type parameter into the `useState` function? as in `useState<Something>`. that way you're unifying those types, also, what about typing info as `Record<'a'|'b'|'c'|'d', [Something, React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<Something>>]>`

Comment: useState<Something> works. I’d like to understand why though.

Comment: the type signature for useState is: `<T>(default: T): [T, (new: T) => void]`. So if you pass Something as an argument you make sure that a,b,c and d are all of type Something